# Angular Unit Test: Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'logout'

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine

I am always getting this error randomly for differennt tests when I enable my login.spec.ts tests.
*Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'logout'*

I tried to fake the logout method in authService using:
spyOn(authService, 'logout').and.returnValues(true);
But still it doesnt work.
Please help figuring out the issue here.

## login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggingIn = false;
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

## authService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public userSource: BehaviorSubject<string | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<string | undefined>(undefined);

  constructor(
    private myRoute: Router) {
    }
  logout() { // TODO: Right now this is fake logout. We need to either destroy express session or cookie.
    this.userSource.next(undefined);
    this.myRoute.navigate(['logout']);
  }
}
```

and now my

## login.component.spec.ts

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [ AuthService,
        ConfigService
      ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule,
      HttpClientTestingModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you mark the answer as the correct one if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error because you haven't configured the routes even you have used `RouterTestingModule` here. Configure your `imports` section of the spec as follows but I don't think calling `logout` function at the `onInit` is a proper implementation.

```js
imports: [
   RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent }
   ]),
   HttpClientTestingModule
]
```

Tell me if this works, and we'll figure out from there. I think even if this fix your problem It hardly test your test case.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same behavior as described here, but my test doesn't use `RouterTestingModule`, nor does the code under test. I'll keep digging to find where this router dependency comes from.

Comment: @Simon Please share the code, I'll be happy to help

Comment: thanks for the offer. I currently don't even know what code to share. As the test failure pops up randomly, it seems any test could fail, even none of the failures so far had anything to do with routing. I'll post again once I know more

Comment: Figured out my issue: a component `MyVerify` runs checks in `ngOnInit` through a service, `observable.subscribe` then redirects to /public/login. The corresponding spec.ts was missing this route in the `RouterTestingModule`. The tricky part is that as the observable subscribe (with the missing route) ran **after the test finished**, the failure **was attributed to the next spec.ts**

Comment: I see, In this case you could use a delay (eg. `tick`) or `whenstable` with `fakeasync` to take this into account. :) Cheers!!